# What are some of the underlying harmonies/scales behind this type of songs?

Tags: scales, harmony

Recently, I came across an album by a guitarist that sounded quite "exotic" and wanted to know more about the theory behind the sounds.

Some interesting phrases: 2:00, 3:57, 7:49

He plays a lot of "droning" chords and plays varying little phrases as a follow-up. If I had to take a shot in the dark, I think he's playing a bunch of suspended chords and some sort of jazz modal lines? I'd appreciate it if someone here can point out more specific and concrete ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 1) it's a transcription question (off topic) and 2) video link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

The chord at 3:25 sounds like a Cm7 add2: Here's a link to somebody showing close -voiced chords on the guitar: